# How to export all rules from SonarQube Quality Profile to SpotBugs, Checkstyle and PMD rule files

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle, pmd, spotbugs

## Issue

I am using **SonarQube 7.9.1**. I have Quality Profile containing ~450 active rules for Java code. There are exporters for **FindBugs**, **PMD** and **Checkstyle** in SonarQube, but they are not exporting all available rules. After export ~20 rules are missing. What can be the cause of that?

Example of missing rule: **"Unnecessary imports should be removed"**.
It seems strange, because both Checkstyle and PMD have such rule available.

## Question

Is it possible to export all rules defined in SonarQube Quality Profile to Checkstyle, PMD and SpotBugs rule files?

Comment: Please, add examples of the rules missing. What have you investigated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing, that you enabled SonarQube rule [RSPEC-1128 Unnecessary imports should be removed](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1128) and now you want to have enabled UnusedImportsCheck in Checkstyle ruleset file. I don't think the exporter works in this way. It just takes all enabled rules of a specified tool and export them in a file. It means that if you enable UnusedImportsCheck Checktyle rule, I'm sure it will be in the exported file.

> Is it possible to export all rules defined in SonarQube Quality Profile to Checkstyle, PMD and SpotBugs rule files?

It is possible to export:

- Checkstyle rules to Checktyle ruleset file
- PMD rules to PMD ruleset file
- etc

It is impossible to export SonarQube rules as different tool rules, example:

- SQUID rules to Checktyle ruleset file

Comment: It answers my question. I thought that SonarQube has some mapping of its rules to rules in Checkstyle, PMD and FindBugs, but it is not true.